# Read/Write files from relative paths after TypeScript compilation in node

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have the following folder structure:

```
/
  /src/
    file.ts
    one.txt
  /resources/
    two.txt
```

and in `file.ts` I want to read contents of `one.txt` and `two.txt` by doing something like the following:

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

// sync is bad.
fs.readFileSync('one.txt');
fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../resources/file.txt'));
```

Everything works just fine when using `ts-node`.

The problem is that when I run `tsc` it compiles all files to `/dist` (which I have told the compiler to do in `tsconfig.json` by setting `outDir` to `./dist`), but both `fs.readFileSync(...)` fail, because the `*.txt` files are not copied to `/dist`, so `fs` can not find the files.

**Now, my question is:** Is there a *beautiful* way to handle this, and make `fs` read and writes work as expected both, when using `ts-node`, and after `tsc`?

I've managed to handle this in several projects by doing something weird like:

```js
// file.ts
const getResourcesDir = () => {
  const dir = path.basename(path.dirname(__dirname));

  if (dir === 'dist') {
    return path.resolve(__dirname, '../../resources');
  } else {
    return path.resolve(__dirname, '../resources');
  }
}
```

But this seems just wrong. I believe that there should be a nicer solution, but I can't find it.

Comment: Use a module like [`cpx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpx) or [`npm-build-tools`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-build-tools) to copy your `.txt` files from `src` to `dist` in a script you put in `postbuild`.

Comment: Alternatively, consider placing static files outside the `src` directory and then using `_dirname` to access.  If you're in `src/my/app.js`, then `path.join(_dirname, '../../resources/file.txt')` will be the same for `dist/my/app.js`.

Answer (score -1):

```
dir =  path.basename(path.dirname(__dirname));
const certDir = (dir === 'dist' ? './dist/cert': '../cert');
console.log('Cert file', certDir, `${certDir}/server-key.pem`);
console.log('Key file', certDir, `${certDir}/server-key.pem`);
```